# Setting Content on 3 Separate Static TableViewCells that are of the same type

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview where a single prototype cell is used only 3 times. This cell has some buttons on it that trigger displaying and hiding content within the cell.

I could reuse the cells, but that requires a lot of resetting each cell so that if I expand A's content, B's content isn't expanded when it loads. Furthermore, this requires me to keep a state record in the Controller class, where I would prefer to have this all handled by the Cell itself for modularity. In other words, the amount of work to keep each cell in the correct stage seems inefficient.

What would be the best way to go about this? Do I use static cells? Is there a way to instance 3 separate cells of the same type and place them in the TableView?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can have the modular part of the code you need inside the cell itself. If you don't want to reuse the cells, then add a custom initializer with a `case` for each cell type. Inside your delegate method `cellForRow`:

`return CustomCell(type: .myCustomType)`

If you do it this way, you can add a switch inside the cell's initializer & set up the cells according to their types that way. And i'm assuming by "static" you mean just three instances. You "add" cells to the table by telling the delegate the number of cells that it will need, which will in turn call `cellForRow` *x* times.